# Why is Editing SessionStore Between Views in Django not Working

Tags: django, django-sessions, django-cookies

I have a session in django using `django.sessions` that I wish to alter using the `SessionStore`, but when I alter the Store and refresh the page (which is naturally updated by django's session middleware), the values are not persisted.

For example, here is my initial response, I set the cookies so I can gather the `SessionStore` in the next view (it may seem off to use Cookies and Sessions together like this, but I have my reasons not related to this post, I am not able to access django.sessions from the view I initially gather the cookies from):

```
next = f"{request.path}"
response = redirect(f"{reverse('quickbooks_authentication', args=[request.client_url])}?quickbooks_account_id={quickbooks_account.pk}&next={next}")
response.set_cookie('session_key', request.session.session_key)
response.set_cookie('client_url', client_url)
return response
```

Then in the next view, all is printing out as expected:

```
print(request.COOKIES.get('session_key')) # tmcdnowypuzcrndtw117hnjxgsruzddj --valid

store = SessionStore(session_key=request.COOKIES.get('session_key'))

store['testing'] = 'test'
store.save()
print(store.modified)  # True
print(store['testing'])  # test

return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

But when I go back to the page, the session was not updated as `store['testing']` does not exist. Why, what am I doing wrong?

```
store = SessionStore(session_key=request.COOKIES.get('session_key'))  # same key as before
store['testing']  # key error
```

Comment: I note that SessionStore has a load() method. Do you need to call that explicitly? eg, `store.load()` before using the key.

Comment: @SamSparx I did not test that explicitly, but I do know that calling `store.values()` did not show the change in the console, so my thought is that the data was not saved as the key, or existing/decoded values did not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems silly to me as there is a new query for the `SessionStore` in both views using `SessionStore(session_key=request.COOKIES.get('session_key'))`, but the solution was to set the actual `request.session` to the newly defined/updated Store, like so:

```
...
store['testing'] = 'test'
store.save()
# tah dah, now we are good on reload
request.session = store
```

With that change, I am able to view the session changes, along with the default values I already had between the `SessionStore(session_key=request.COOKIES.get('session_key'))` object and now `request.session`